# How to maintain back stack with history push (without user action) while using ReactRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a react app with proper routing enabled. I am stuck onto a problem where I am not able to manage back stack when I navigate (from /home) to another page using props.history.push() without user action. That means when "home" page loads I want to check some condition (async) in componentDidMount and navigate automatically to another page. When I do this, there is nothing goes to back stack. My app just exits on back press. Ideally it should go back to home page.

But when I do that async task on a button click on home page and navigate to another page, routing works correctly and on back press it takes to home page.